# Error inspite of single quotes in curl code

Tags: curl

I am trying the following CURL code based on the following page code:
https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/insights/

It always gives following error in my Bash Terminal:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Unexpected )","locations":[{"line":1,"column":20}]}]}
```

(ID and token changed in below code)

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "X-OPENTOK-AUTH:T1==QmY3JlYXRlX3RpbWU9MTU1MjMwNjIzOSZyb2xlPXB1Ymxpc2hlciZub25jZT0xNTUyMzA2MjM5LjE5MjU2NjQ2NTI0NzMmaW5pdGlhbF9sYXlvdXRfY2xhc3NfbGlzdD0=" \
-d '{"query":"{project(projectId:'${123456789}'){projectData(start:\"'1549887039'\"){resources{usage{streamedSubscribedMinutes}}}}}"}' \
'https://insights.example.com/graphql'
```

Please what is wrong..I tried single quotes and doublequotes masked with backslash but no results.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have picked the wrong url. The correct one should be `https://insights.opentok.com/graphql` (not https://insights.example.com/graphql)

Here is an escaped curl:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://insights.opentok.com/graphql \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'X-OPENTOK-AUTH: T1==QmY3JlYXRlX3RpbWU9MTU1MjMwNjIzOSZyb2xlPXB1Ymxpc2hlciZub25jZT0xNTUyMzA2MjM5LjE5MjU2NjQ2NTI0NzMmaW5pdGlhbF9sYXlvdXRfY2xhc3NfbGlzdD0=' \
  -d '{"query": "{project(projectId:123456789){projectData(start:\"1549887039\"){resources{usage{streamedSubscribedMinutes}}}}}"}'
```

You can create curl-requests using Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/).

https://blog.getpostman.com/2016/02/03/curl-and-postman-work-wonderfully-together/

Good luck!

Comment: I changed it deliberately. Not the issue.

Comment: You are not supposed to send in `'${}'`, they are just placeholders for the variable.

Comment: I am passing it like YOUR_OT_API_KEY= 123456

Comment: Ok good. That's all I can help you with.. Make it work in Postman first, then convert it to curl from there. I haven't used the graphql api before

Answer (score 0):

Pamela, it your code seems correct to me. Please try this as stated on their website.

```
YOUR_OT_API_KEY= 123456               
YOUR_OT_JWT= jwttoken.....
OT_START_DATE=$(($(date +%s)-864000))    
OT_DATA='{"query":"{project(projectId:'${YOUR_OT_API_KEY}'){projectData(start:\"'$OT_START_DATE'\"){resources{usage{streamedSubscribedMinutes}}}}}"}'

curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "X-OPENTOK-AUTH:$YOUR_OT_JWT" \
-d $OT_DATA \
'https://insights.opentok.com/graphql'
```

As an alternative you can try Agora, which offers better support than tokbox and nearly 10,000 minutes FREE every month. Tokbox is costly for production use.

https://www.agora.io/en/videocall/

Answer (score 0):

Opentok QA staff here.

Pamela, you must remove the single quotes (') from the POST data:

```
projectId:'${123456789}'
```

Because the first one will match the one after *-d*